# JS predictive search; find from string anywhere inside the input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web

I am working on predicting the search from an input.

Many searches will start with year/make/model of a car PLUS the part they are searching for

I would love if it was possible to predict after the year/make/model (or even anywhere inside the input after any text) but I'm not sure how to achieve this

eg: 2002 Honda S2000 Brake Ro

It should be able to compare "brake ro" to get "brake rotor" from the set of data

```
function predictSearch(input) {
    const results = [];
    for (i = 0; i < predictiondata.length; i++) {
        if(input.toLowerCase() === predictiondata[i].slice(0, input.length).toLowerCase()) {
            if(results.length < 5) {
                results.push(predictiondata[i].toLowerCase());
            }
        }

    }
    return results;
}
```

I have this but it specifically looks for the prediction data starting from the beginning of the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than interpolating each string to determine if there's a match, it might be worth considering [regex.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to check if each `predictiondata` contains `input` anywhere.

```js
function predictSearch(input) {
    const results = [];
    const regex = new RegExp(`${input}*`);
    for (i = 0; i < predictiondata.length; i++) {
        // Check if input is in predictiondata[i]
        if (regex.test(predictiondata[i])) {
            if (results.length < 5) {
                results.push(predictiondata[i].toLowerCase());
            }
        }

    }
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an SQL database to store the part names?

For a live search in an SQL db with ajax, in your SQL statement you can place percent signs (%) around the variable posted by the ajax, this will search the part names list for any matches to the string pattern from the input, the % signs allow it to check inside of the db's strings for any matches as well.

This video helped me in a similar situation
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCsPAquMNVw&t=2s